# How to remove switchport switchport general allowed from Dell n2048

Tags: network, dell

how to remove switchport general allowed vlan remove 1 from dell n2048

```
interface Gi1/0/1
switchport general allowed vlan remove 1
exit
```

what command for switchport general allowed vlan remove 1

Comment: Did you try `no switchport general allowed vlan remove 1` on the interface?